# Do you use __autoload() ? Will it be compatible to all host?

Tags: php, autoload

I'm hesitating whether or not to use this mechanism. PHP Doc says autoloading is not available if using PHP in CLI interactive mode. So, should we avoid to use this method for just in case, your application get installed in a host happenly running PHP in CLI ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not what it means. CLI interactive mode is when you start the PHP interpreter in command-line without a script (eg. with `php -a`). You can use autoloading in your application without worries.